# Google Maps in J query Tabs not Centering

Tags: jquery, wordpress, google-maps, tabs

Google maps in jQuery tabs has been a problem but i have managed to get them to display in a tab. However, the map is not centred to the address location. Below is my code:

jQuery

```
 // refresh google map
    tab_content.children('li[data-tab="' + data_tab +   '"]').find('iframe[src^="https://www.google.com/maps"],  iframe[src^="http://www.google.com/maps"]').each(function(){
        this.src = this.src;
        jQuery(this).css('opacity','0');
        jQuery(this).delay(400).animate({'opacity': '1'}, 500);
    });
    tab_content.children('li[data-tab="' + data_tab + '"]').find('.themeblvd-gmap').each(function(){
        google.maps.event.trigger(this, 'resize');
    });


    e.preventDefault();
```

Where `themeblvd-gmap` is the wordpress plugin i can using to call the map.

To run the map, the code being used is:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#tb_gmap_<?php echo $id; ?>").gMap({
        maptype: "<?php echo $maptype; ?>",
        zoom: <?php echo $zoom; ?>,
        markers: [
            {
                address: "<?php echo $address; ?>",
                popup: <?php echo $popup; ?>,
                html: "<?php echo $html; ?>"
            }
        ],
        controls: {
            panControl: true,
            zoomControl: true,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            scaleControl: true,
            streetViewControl: false,
            overviewMapControl: false
        }
    });
});
```

Any help i can get to get the map centred?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean centering of address/location in the map or the centering of complete div container?

Comment: @KamleshKushwaha sorry i mean centering of the address/location

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like this:

```
// refresh google map
tab_content.children('li[data-tab="' + data_tab + '"]').find('iframe[src^="https://www.google.com/maps"],  iframe[src^="http://www.google.com/maps"]').each(function () {
    this.src = this.src;
    jQuery(this).css('opacity', '0');
    jQuery(this).delay(400).animate({
        'opacity': '1'
    }, 500);
});
tab_content.children('li[data-tab="' + data_tab + '"]').find('.themeblvd-gmap').each(function () {
    var c = this.getCenter();
    google.maps.event.trigger(this, 'resize');
    this.setCenter(c);
});
e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: This does not work as it breaks off the map. Only a portion of the map is displayed with the other areas being greyed out

Comment: The error is `Uncaught ReferenceError: map is not defined`

Comment: I think you need to initialise the map again before you use the above code. Just call the initialize() function or whatever function you are using before these three lines of code.

Comment: sorry..what do you mean?

Comment: You must be using some function to initialise the map with the options such as location,zoom etc. Just call that function or code before triggering the resize on map. See the updated answer.

Comment: map object in your code in undefined, you need to initialise the map object again in order to perform any other actions on it.

Comment: Ive updated my question with the code thats being used to run the map. Would this help?

Comment: this give me an error in the console `function initialize() $("#tb_gmap_1667080356")` error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function `

Comment: Probably this will help you for the errors: https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1LENP_enIN492IN492&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=undefined%20is%20not%20a%20function%20gMap

Comment: Try using js script code after you html element i.e. place your js code after <div id="tb_gmap_523362154" class="themeblvd-gmap" style="height:280px"></div> and also place the google map script tag before the gmap plugin script tag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55508/discussion-between-kamlesh-kushwaha-and-user2725936).

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?